# Magento 2 : How to solve Catalog Rule Product Status: REINDEX REQUIRED ( NO SSH access )

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex, cli, command

I have problem with Catalog Rule Product Status: **REINDEX REQUIRED.**

I'm using Magento 2.2.3 & DirectAdmin without SSH access. 
Also, I triad through Admin panel & it's not working.

My Cron-job are okay.
I don't have any problems with it.
Please help. I'm exhausted.. :(

[image: Catalog Rule Product Status: REINDEX REQUIRED]

[image: Cron jobs]

Comment: I realize this is of no help, but I can assure you that using Magento 2 will be very problematic if you have no ssh access.  There are a number of things that will require you to have SSH access and run CLI commands.  I highly recommend getting access asap, and either way, good luck!

Comment: Thank you dear for your tip. I have it already. they just add it to my hosting account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php's [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function to resolve your problem.

Create a php file, command.php in your magento's root and put following code in it ;

```
<?php
system("php bin/magento inderxer:reset");
system("php bin/magento inderxer:reindex");
```

Hit the php file through your browser by hitting `yourstoreurl.com/command.php`, you will execute the commands mentioned in file and get the respective output from the command to your browser window.